# Advantages of microsoft graph api's over Onenote api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I am working on Onenote integration for our application. I am new to onenote and microsoft graph. I don't understand the advantage of using graph api over rest api's provided by Onenote. Only authentication will be done through a common point for work/business and personal account that's the only difference.

Please help me in advantages of using graph api over individual application rest services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs

Microsoft Graph exposes multiple APIs from Office 365 and other Microsoft cloud services through a single endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com. Microsoft Graph simplifies queries that would otherwise be more complex.

You can use Microsoft Graph to:

Access data from multiple Microsoft cloud services, including Azure Active Directory, Exchange Online as part of Office 365, SharePoint, OneDrive, OneNote, Planner and Microsoft Teams.

Navigate between entities and relationships.

Access intelligence and insights from the Microsoft cloud (for commercial users).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amol. I do understand that using single endpoint we can access multiple MS-Cloud services. My use case is just to integrate onenote and sharepoint in my application. Microsoft graph doesn't provide any advantages over the api which are provided by these individual services, this is what my understanding is.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think they will be phasing out the product-specific APIs in favour of Microsoft Graph API. For the Azure Active Directory Graph API at least, this has already been [communicated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

Comment: Having to use a common endpoint and unified authentication is a great advantage. You wont gain any additional functionality by using Microsoft Graph as of now, but your application code will become simpler.

Comment: Agreed with Amol.  Why go through the trouble to get extra auth tokens, one for each service, maybe force a user to log in multiple times?  Have user log in once, and hit the graph. Not to mention you will then be able to access other parts of the graph if your application requires it (e.g. Emails)

Comment: Going forward, all API engineering attention will be heavily focused on Microsoft Graph. While several product specific APIs will continue to exist and be maintained, many APIs will only be available from Graph (for example, Modern Groups and Teams are Graph only APIs). If you're slinging new code, I highly suggest slinging it at Graph.

Comment: Thank you all for your response. Will confirm if graph api's for onenote supports all the operations and will start using that. One shortcoming that I could find is as -( The location can be user notebooks on Office 365 or consumer OneDrive, and group notebooks on Office 365. SharePoint site-hosted notebooks is currently not supported. )